# Asp.net adding parameter to url string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm displaying a list of filtered items in a page, and now I have to limit the displaying by paginating the results.

So if I have url parameters like these:

```
example.com/?category=pizza&period=today
```

where both category and period can also not being showed:

```
example.com/?period=today

example.com/
```

how can I add a "Next page" in the end that keeps any previous parameter and adds

```
&pagenum=5
```

or if there are no parameters:

```
?pagenum=5
```

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this client or server side?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For serverside

```
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
url += (Request.QueryString.ToString() == "" ) ? "?pagenum=1" : "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString() + "&pagenum=1";
```

You can pass in the page number depending on how you are handling this.

Answer (score -1):

For ASP.Net use the following:

```
string temp = Request.QueryString["yourParamName"];
```

Fissh