# Asp.net Permanent redirection Body,Path,QueryString,Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

in My Scenario.

I want to redirect all request to another domain that includes Path,QueryStrings,Method,Content

Example
Some user send request to my domain.

```
POST www.mydomain.com/service?id=5
HEADER { 
token:securityToken
UserAgent: Chrome
Accept: application/json
}
BODY
{
Content lorem ipsum
}
```

I 'll Check some parameters and change token in the header.

Then

I want to send this request to another domain.

```
POST www.anotherdomain.com/service?id=5
HEADER {
token:newsecurityToken
UserAgent: Chrome
Accept: application/json
}
BODY
{
Content lorem ipsum
}
```

Finally

User will get anotherdomain's response. Is it Possible ?

Server : Windows server 2008
.Net Framework : 4.0

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with throttling?

Comment: mydomain will throttle anotherdomain's requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the request come back through your domain, your best bet would be to make a request of your own to the external domain. I'd give more details about how, but I don't know what version of .net you are using. Here is one post that outlines a method.

[Relaying a request in asp.net (Forwarding a request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697177/relaying-a-request-in-asp-net-forwarding-a-request)

It basically says to create a new `WebRequest`, set the relevant properties, get the response, and send the information from the response back to the user.

I kind of feel like I have to ask this, are you sure you aren't trying to phish or something? On second thought, never mind. ;)

Update:

Since you don't need it to go through your domain, I would recommend using a 301 redirect. Here's a post where someone does it in begin request

[301 redirect in asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673303/301-redirect-in-asp-net-4-0)

> ```
> void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
> {
>     // Code that runs on every request
>     if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.net"))
>     {
>         HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
>         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://website.net", "http://www.website.net"));
>     }
> }
> ```

Note that this post also offers a way to do it through url rewriting in web.config if there isn't any complicated logic to determine if you want to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for answer. this topic helps me. Could I use that codes in global.asax > begin_request  . But Path and Querystring are missing. I can add this properties to request. 

And Framework version is 4.0,
Request doesn't have to comeback through my domain.

Comment: If it doesn't have to come back through your domain, then I would absolutely just 301 redirect them

Comment: How can I do it, after audit request ? I shouldn't use IIS redirection.

Comment: I tried to use 301 redirect. But it converts post request to get request. and There is no Request body and custom Headers. :(

Comment: I fixed my problem . Solution is on the first linq what @parKing shared (Relaying a Request in Asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw an idea out because I've never seen this approach before, is there a reason you can't use SOAP webservices to accomplish this?

[pass values to an object to webservices webmethod C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024625/pass-values-to-an-object-to-webservices-webmethod-c-sharp)

They were more or less created for this type of thing and would make your life a whole lot easier.  Otherwise, you can use URL parameters

[Asp.net adding parameter to url string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445517/asp-net-adding-parameter-to-url-string)

Or, just pass the values using POST & GET requests appropriately.  POST to domain B & have a listener waiting for that POST that will parse those values.  I'd go with the web services, they're easier than they look.

Comment: None of them, There is an API like Facebook API. I have a lot of client projects which uses this API.  So , I need to audit this client projects Like Read Data Limit , Write Data Limit. I 'll take all request, then I 'll send to facebook API after audit.

Comment: Interesting so let's see if I'm understanding this correct.  FB API > client app > you > FB API?

Comment: Yes you are right.  myAPI should be between myclientprojects and facebookAPI. MyAPI will control everything.